# How to set the size of font in tabs in MacVim?

Tags: fonts, macvim

I have a usable font size in the body of MacVim, but the font size in the tabs is too tiny.  Is there a control for that? `":set gfn=*"` doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: OP, can you add a screenshot or something to show which font you're talking about?

Comment: @Rob, where did you have this discussion? Is there a meta post about it? As far as I can tell, this question is [still](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287089/354577) [fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294857/354577) to [post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401013/354577). Like VSCode, Visual Studio, PyCharm, Sublime Text, etc., vi is a tool commonly used by programmers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255909/discussion-between-chris-and-rob).

Comment: The most recent Meta discussion about it, from 2022, seems to indicate moderators and the community feel questions about code editors (which arguably includes Vim) are on-topic here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418698/when-a-question-pertains-to-specifically-configuring-an-editor-shouldnt-it-be